# How can I select the record with the latest date in each group

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have a table which we'll call table:
table(id: integer, pid: integer, end: datetime)

that has the following data:

```
table:
id    pid   end
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     2     11
5     2     12
6     2     13
7     3     21
8     3     22
9     3     23
10    4     31
11    4     32
12    4     33
```

What I need to do is select the ids of the records, grouped by pid, with the highest end value. My output (as an ActiveRecord::Relation) should be as follows:

```
[#<Table id: 3, pid: 1, end: 3>,
 #<Table id: 6, pid: 2, end: 13>,
 #<Table id: 9, pid: 3, end: 23>,
 #<Table id: 12, pid: 4, end: 33>]
```

Any direction you can give me is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job

```
    select `id` , `pid` , `end` from table1
    where `end` in (select max(`end`) from table1)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70b54/9)

DUE to your suggest try this  **edit** :

```
     select `id` , `pid` , `end` from 
    ( select max(id) id ,`pid` ,max(`end`) as `end` from table1 group by `pid`)t
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71645/6)

Comment: I think that this would work but I have noticed a problem in the formulation of my question. In practice, the end value in each group will not be the same. I will edit my question to account for this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work even if your max `end` doesn't always correspond to max `id` and if there are several `id`'s with same maximal `end`.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.pid, t1.end FROM Table1 t1
JOIN 
(SELECT pid AS 'pid2', MAX(end) AS 'end2' FROM Table1 GROUP BY pid) t2
ON t2.pid2=t1.pid AND t2.end2=t1.end
#GROUP BY t1.pid  #in case there are several records with same 'pid' and 'end' and you want to select any one of those
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0058d/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select id,pid,end from Table1 order by pid asc, end desc) abc
group by pid;
```

[**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ff62/4)